# systemd networking basics: cannot switch from DHCP to static IP address

Tags: systemd, static-ip, systemd-networkd

I'm just starting with systemd networking, and I can't set up a new system with a static IP address. This is a default Ubuntu 20.04 server, and network-manager and ifupdown are not installed (so no /etc/network/interfaces, etc).

By default, the server boots up with DHCP enabled, and gets an IP address, and everything works. I've now added an /etc/systemd/network/static.network file which contains a basic setup:

```
[Match]
Name=e*

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.20/24
Gateway=192.168.1.40
```

If I do a `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` this is ignored, and `systemctl status` shows that an address of 192.168.1.10 was assigned from DHCP (`enp1s0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.1.10/24 via 192.168.1.40`). I get the same result if I reboot; the address is still the DHCP one. It seems as if the `static.network` file is being completely ignored, but it is being processed - if I add an obvious error to the file it is reported by the status command. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

The server is actually a VM running under RHEL 8, which I'm hoping is not relevant.

Comment: You should be using [netplan.io](https://netplan.io/) to configure your networks on Ubuntu.

Comment: @ArturMeinild: the datacentre isn't keen on netplan; they say they have problems with it. They would rather I use /etc/network/interfaces. Best option, I think, is to use systemd, since that's more portable and "standard". I think.

Comment: Hey QF0! Cross-posting is generally not considered as a good practice in Stack Exchange. I suggest you to go through this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068. Also, please consider going through the [tour] page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this looks like a bug on 20.04. `.network` files are meant to be processed in lexical order, according to this extract from the `systemd-networkd` [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html):

> The .network files are read from the files located in the system
> network directories /usr/lib/systemd/network and
> /usr/local/lib/systemd/network, the volatile runtime network directory
> /run/systemd/network and the local administration network directory
> /etc/systemd/network. All configuration files are collectively sorted
> and processed in lexical order, regardless of the directories in which
> they live.

However, if I turn on `systemd-networkd` debugging (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1187633/how-to-debug-systemd-networkd) if you don't know how), it turns out that the *lowest*-lexically-sorted file has precedence. I can't be entirely sure, because the logs don't show the processing order, and only stop at the first hit for the relevant network interface.

This is what I know, for the plain Ubuntu 20.04 server install:

1. There are 5 `.network` files across the system
2. One of these is created by netplan at runtime, and is `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp1s0.network`
3. My new file is `/etc/systemd/network/static.network`
4. On `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` the netplan file takes precedence over my own
5. If I manually remove the netplan file, and restart networking, my file is acted on. However, this is only temporary till the next reboot
6. If I rename my file to `05-static.network` then it takes precedence over the netplan file

Ergo, processing order broken, unless I'm doing something stupid.

As a temporary fix you need to give your file a low lexical order by prefixing with something like `05-`. However, this might break on a future update if the processing order is reversed. A better fix would be to disable netplan (not sure how to do this), but this might also break if something else then decides it has to create a `.network` file to make up for the missing netplan one.

**Edit - removing netplan**

You can remove netplan entirely with `apt purge netplan.io`. However, this may not be a good idea - it also removes `cloud-init`, for example, which is required by DigitalOcean. So:

```
# cd /etc/netplan
# rm 00-installer-config.yaml
# netplan apply
```

After a reboot, you no longer get the auto-generated `.network` file, and can use normal file naming in your `.network` files without a conflict.